# Case Insensitive findall in Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I have to parse XML that has tag names that may be in any case (mixed, upper, lower, etc) and I don't know what the case will be beforehand. How can I make findall be totally case insensitive in ElementTree?

```
   # Does not work
   variables = message.findall("VaRiAbLE")
```

Comment: because `XML` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I understand that XML is case sensitive. I don't control the generation of this XML so the question stands... How can findall search for a tag that may appear in any case? Boost iptree does it. I assumed ElementTree would too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply get the string from the tree, lowercase it, and remake the tree. Then it should be parseable

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def to_parseable(tree):
    t = ET.tostring(tree)
    t = t.lower()
    return ET.fromstring(t)
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of all the solutions I tried, this approach works best. I agree that I shouldn't have to do this as the creator of the XML should use consistent case in tag and attribute names, but when it's out of your control and you must deal with this sort of XML, then this approach in ElementTree works.

Comment: Wtf, why are you doing this? At least use regex to make this only apply to the tag and attribute names, jeez.

Comment: That's not good. The above code converts to lowercase the usefull data also.

Comment: This is terrible! When you're done, all of the XML data is lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue. Note this is probably horrific in terms of performance but is great at extracted XML attributes from elements.

```
def getInsensitiveAttrbiute(element, key) :

   keyRegex = re.compile(key, re.IGNORECASE)
   for key in element.attrib.keys() :
       if keyRegex.match(key) :
           return element.attrib[key]
   raise KeyError


element = ET.fromstring('<FOO src="BAR" />')
print getInsensitiveAttrbiute(element, "sRc")
```