# Python ET parse XML insensitive case

Tags: python, xml

I want to parse a XML file using [ET library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). Everything works fine, but now, I want to do the same ignoring uppercase or lowercase.

For example: I have this line in my code:

```
root2.findall(".EQUIPMENT/SIGNAL[@NAME='" + signalName + "']/VALUE_FORMAT")
```

where signalName is 'S_Pitch' in my XML file, but I have 'S_PITCH' in my python variable.

Any idea?

Comment: You can do case-insensitive matches against attribute values with XPath expressions, but ET only supports a small subset. You could switch to using `lxml`, which implements proper XPath support.

Comment: Look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440896/case-insensitive-findall-in-python-elementtree . You will get your answer

Comment: OK. A lot of thanks.